# DialogFragments with devices api level < 11

Tags: android, android-layout, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-fragments

I am in the process of making a honeycomb project/fork backwards compatible with 1.6+.

Based on the documentation provided by Google/Android I decided to build off all my fragments off `DialogFragment`s which worked great for honeycomb...it gives me the flexibility to put anything as a dialog or 'full screen' element.

I've now incorporated the compatibility kit and moved my imports and method calls over to that. Now that I'm on 2.3 I am trying to launch an identical intent but I receive this issue:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: DialogFragment can not be attached to a container view
```

The documentation for `DialogFragment` suggests that it can perform as `Fragment` when you don't desire the dialog/popup functionality.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I managed to fix this properly in `DialogFragment.java` of the Compatibility Package:

Change line 74:
`boolean mShowsDialog = false;`

Comment out line 232: `//mShowsDialog = mContainerId == 0;`

Then change the two show methods to this:

```
public void show(FragmentManager manager, String tag) {
    this.setShowsDialog(true);
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(this, tag);
    ft.commit();
}

// JavaDoc removed
public int show(FragmentTransaction transaction, String tag) {
    this.setShowsDialog(true);
    transaction.add(this, tag);
    mRemoved = false;
    mBackStackId = transaction.commit();
    return mBackStackId;
}
```

Basically, they did write in support but the toggle to switch between dialog/embedded doesn't work.

So here we default to embedded, and then set to show as a dialog just before we show it.

Comment: Also: `onSaveInstanceState` should only save `mShowsDialog` if it's `true`. You only have to remove the `!` from the `if`.

Comment: On which revision (aka SHA1 commit id from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support) is this changeset based on? I am trying to reproduce your fix with the current version of the support library, but am having trouble doing it correctly as apparently Google did not tag with the r<n> revision code they are using for releases. I have tried with commit  863d7b4.

Comment: I meant: I have compared your changeset with commit 863d7b4.

Comment: Incorporating your changes into DialogFragment doesn't fix the IllegalStateException for me. BTW, I try to show the DialogFragment as a Dialog.

Comment: These fixes were made 13 months ago. Google have since fixed this themselves.

Comment: just checked v11 of support library and still have this bug

Comment: Also still seeing this. Any other solutions available?

Comment: Derp, I had this issue because I override getView in my fragment and returned the wrong view, which had a parent view. That triggered the crash in my case.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment version, please check [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem. I never found a "correct" solution, but you can do the same thing by setting the theme of the Dialog in `OnCreateDialog()`. By setting the theme to `android.R.style.Theme_Holo_DialogWhenLarge` the dialog will be shown as a dialog on large and xlarge screens, while it'll be shown as a full screen window on small and normal screens.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_DialogWhenLarge);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using a DialogFragment child class and doing this trick in the onCreate() works. I call setShowsDialog() before onCreate() is called (in the onAttachFragment() of my Activity)

```
public class DialogFragmentHosted extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        boolean forceShowDialog = savedInstanceState==null;
        boolean showsDialog = getShowsDialog();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (forceShowDialog )
            setShowsDialog(showsDialog);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the application note?  It shows a recommended way of embedding a dialog, and I've verified this works on 2.2.1.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#DialogOrEmbed

My fragment layout had to change to conform but it was quick and easy.  It's more natural to be able to define the dialog fragment in XML and expect it to be embedded without any extra work (as the above changes to Compat API would support); and to only expect modal behavior when called through show().  I suppose that isn't the current behavior.