# Android Compiling Compatibility Package: DialogFragment.java changes

Tags: android, compilation, package, compatibility, android-dialogfragment

I have [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637894/dialogfragments-with-devices-api-level-11) ( DialogFragment can not be attached to a container view) which the linked stackoverflow post will hopefully resolve.

However I'm stuck when it comes to regenerating the android-support-v4.jar file, I have also tried including all the folders in /android-sdk-linux_86/extras/android/compatibility/v4/src/ directly into my project which also just gives 100's of compiler errors in Eclipse.

I have also tried implementing some of the solutions further down in that post but they do not seem to work for me.

So how do you rebuild the android-support-v4.Jar file or is there an easier way to get these code modifications into me Eclipse project?

I am Targeting `Android 2.2 API` level 8 under Eclipse Helios.

Thanks

Michael

Answer (score 0):

The Java source code for the **Android Support Library V4** is located in the directory *android-sdk\extras\android\support\v4\src*

If you want to build it as a project in Eclipse, you'd copy everything from the *java* directory so you get a package structure as **android/support/v4** in Eclipse, and then from each other directory (*eclair*, *froyo*, *gingerbread* and so on), copy everything from below it's parent folder (parent: eclair) and only copy the children (child: *android*).

Then from Eclipse, build it and export the JAR file.